# Length of curve $X_2(t) = (t\cos t, t\sin t)$ where $(0 \le t \le 2\pi)$

Tags: proof-verification, curves, conjectures, parameter-estimation

Here I got $X_2(t) = (t\cos t, t\sin t)$ where $(0 \le t \le 2\pi)$

Let $X_2(t) = (x, y)$ then $x^2 + y^2 = t^2 \;\;\forall t\in[0, 2\pi]$

now will divide $[0,2\pi]$ into $n-identical$ segments.

then we get $[0, \frac{2\pi}{n},2\frac{2\pi}{n},..k\frac{2\pi}{n}, (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n},...n\frac{2\pi}{n} ]$

then we take $kth$ and $(k+1)th$ term, and measure the distance between two:

$d(X_2(k\frac{2\pi}{n}),X_2((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})) = \sqrt{[k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}-(k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})]^2+[k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}-(k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})]^2}=\sqrt{k^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2+(k+1)^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2-2k(k+1)(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2[\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}]} $

then if we let $n\rightarrow \infty$, we can estimate that $[\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}] \rightarrow 1$ thus  $d(X_2(k\frac{2\pi}{n}),X_2((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})) \rightarrow \frac{2\pi}{n}$ thus, total length would be $\frac{2\pi}{n}\cdot n = 2\pi$

I had developed my own conjecture as denoted above, and wants to be verified and get some correction for illogical reasoning.

Any harsh ones are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arc length is equal to

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

We have $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}=\cos t-t\sin t$ and $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt}=\sin t+t\cos t$

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2=(\cos t-t\sin t)^2+(\sin t+t\cos t)^2=1+t^2$$

Let $t=\tan\theta$. The arc length is

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt&=\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\sec\theta d\tan\theta\\
&=\Big[\sec\theta\tan\theta\Big]_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}-\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta\\
&=2\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1
}-\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}(\sec^3\theta-\sec\theta) d\theta\\
&=2\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1
}-\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\sec\theta d\tan\theta+\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\sec\theta d\theta\\
&=\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1
}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\sec\theta d\theta\\
&=\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1
}+\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)\Big]_{\theta=0}^{\tan\theta=2\pi}\\
&=\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1
}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{4\pi^2+1}+2\pi)
\end{align}

The estimated arc length is not correct.

---

The estimate of OP is incorrect at one point

It is correct that

$d(X_2(k\frac{2\pi}{n}),X_2((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})) =\sqrt{k^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2+(k+1)^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2-2k(k+1)(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2[\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}]} $

Note that

$$\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}=\cos[(k+1)-k]\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

So,

$$d(X_2(k\frac{2\pi}{n}),X_2((k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n})) =\frac{2\pi}{n}\sqrt{k^2+(k+1)^2-2k(k+1)\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}} $$

The arc length is approximately $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2\pi}{n}\sqrt{k^2+(k+1)^2-2k(k+1)\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}}$.

We cannot replace $\sqrt{k^2+(k+1)^2-2k(k+1)\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ by $\sqrt{k^2+(k+1)^2-2k(k+1)}$ as there are many terms. Although $\displaystyle \cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is close to $1$, the error cumulatives when there are many terms.

Comment: Why does my conjecture have some gap with real length?

Comment: If we take $n=100$, the length of the first line segment is approximately 0.062831853 and the length of the last line segment is approximately 0.397734946. The difference is quite big. The error of the estimation is too large.

Comment: @Beverlie The estimation is incorrect as we cannot take $\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$ as $1$. Please read my edited solution

Answer (score 1):

Although the idea is nice and the result is true, I see a problem in your argument. You say, that you like to approximate 
$$
\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}
$$
with $1$ since $n$ goes to infinity. But this is not valid. An example where this argument fail: 
$$
e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\neq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n=1
$$ although $1+\frac1n\to 1$ for $n\to\infty$.

But your argument can be fixed with a small change:

You can write
$$
\sqrt{k^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2+(k+1)^2(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2-2k(k+1)(\frac{2\pi}{n})^2[\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}]}
=\frac{2\pi}{n}\underbrace{\sqrt{k^2+(k+1)^2-2k(k+1)\left(\cos k\frac{2\pi}{n}\cos (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}+\sin k\frac{2\pi}{n}\sin (k+1)\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}}_{=:f(n)}
$$
Your approximated length is now $n\frac{2\pi}nf(n)=2\pi f(n)$.

Now it is easy to see, that $f(n)\to 1$ for $n\to\infty$ without problems.

Comment: awesome. thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You already recevied a nice answer from Mundron Schmidt.

Using you approach and simplifying as much as I could, we can arrive to $$d^2=\frac{4 \pi ^2}{n^2} \left(1+4 k (k+1) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right) \right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Now, we can use Taylor series for infinitely large values of $n$ $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)=\frac{\pi }{n}-\frac{\pi ^3}{6 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ $$\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)=\frac{\pi ^2}{n^2}-\frac{\pi ^4}{3 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ $$d^2=\frac{4 \pi ^2}{n^2} \left(1+\frac{4 \pi ^2 k (k+1)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$ $$d=\frac{2\pi}n \left(1+\frac{2 \pi ^2 k (k+1)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Why does my conjecture have some gap with real length?

Comment: To me, there is no gap. If I compute the arc length between the two points and expand the result as Taylor series, I get $$d=\frac{2\pi}n \left(1+\frac{2 \pi ^2 k (k+1)+\frac{2\pi^2}3}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Then CY Aries 's anwer is wrong?

Comment: @Beverlie. I do not understand why the interation was done between $0$ and $2\pi$. What I did was just to use your steps between the two points.